# How to set DataTemplate element during initialization - 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException'

Tags: c#, xaml

I have got this part of XAML code with DataTemplate:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Collapsed" x:Name="licenseGrid">
 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
 <ListBox x:Name="LicensesListBox" Grid.Row="0" 
       Margin="12,10,12,0" Visibility="Visible"
       ItemsSource="{Binding Licenses}">
   <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto"></Setter>
    </Style>
   </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate x:Name="dt">
             <toolkit:ToggleSwitch x:Name="ts" Header="{Binding Header}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

During initialization of the page I want to set some value to ToggleSwitch elements but in this part of code 'library' is null and I got 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException'.

```
public Page1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    LicenseViewModel licenseViewModel = new LicenseViewModel();
    licenseViewModel.GetLicenses();
    this.DataContext = licenseViewModel;

    SetLicenseData();
}

private void SetLicenseData()
{
    // Code for other non DataTemplate XAML elements that works

    for (int i = 0; i < LicensesListBox.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        ListBoxItem library = (ListBoxItem)(LicensesListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i));
        ToggleSwitch ts = FindFirstElementInVisualTree<ToggleSwitch>(library);
        // another lines with code...
    }
}
```

I guess it is because ListBox is not fully loaded in that moment but I don't know how to fix this. Thank you for any help.

Comment: You must wait LayoutUpdated Event

Comment: You should also consider that in some configuration the only elements that are generated are only those that fit in the view.

Comment: You mean add LayoutUpade event to ListBox and call SetLicenseData() there? That doesn't help.

Comment: it doesn't work for any element or just for some elements?

Comment: Every ListBoxItem element, 'library' is always null.

Comment: you have a problem in the code by the way `ListBoxItem library = (ListBoxItem)
                 LicensesListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i));` you have )) at the end and there should be only one i think you fixed that

Comment: Yes, that is no problem anymore. I have these lines of code also in another method and there it works, but there is ListBox visibly loaded yet so I guess that's why.

Comment: Are you calling `SetLicenseData()` in your contructor?

Comment: Not anymore, now I call it in LayoutUpade method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally got it. I add Loaded event to ToggleSwitch element and there simply use cast

```
ToggleSwitch ts = sender as ToggleSwitch;
//another lines with code
```